# Payment declined (Google Developer Console)

Tags: in-app-purchase

In my Google Developer Console under "Order Management" I have a lot of cancelled order like that:

Order history

Nov 3 2018 Payment pending. You received a new order.
Nov 3 2018 Payment declined. Process for cancelling the order was initiated.Reason: Payment declined.
Nov 3 2018 Payment declined. The order was cancelled.

This is the history of my in-app purchase order.

Is that Normal? Maybe this happen every time a user click "buy in app-purchase" and than came back?

Someone know when this happen? Thanks

Comment: I am currently facing the same issue, trying to figure it out with the google team. If you have found an answer please post it.

Comment: I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: @AnjaliKamble I was just about to ask the same question, have you found out what the reason behind this? thank you

Comment: @Jack No. I have not found the reason yet.

Comment: same issue here..anyone found the solution ?

Comment: In my case my users gmail account was unverified since it was an unlocked/unactivated phone (it was not linked with any phone number). Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Go to to your developer console https://play.google.com/apps/publish
Click Settings > Payment Settings > Manage Settings.
Ensure your merchant account is not under review and all the statutory requirements are completed. You would see an alert on the top of the Payment Settings Page if any action items are necessary from you as the app developer.

If the merchant account is under compliance then the issue might be with the app users (buyer) payment profile. Google apparently is very sensitive when it comes accepting payments, and rightly so in order to avoid fraudulent payment activities.  Especially since given different country's complex financial and regulatory obligations they seem to have added lot of checks to users play store account verification. Google may want the app user (the buyer) to verify their identity, especially if your phone device is unlocked and does not have a phone number associated with it. The most common reasons for declined payments are unverified gmail account or invalid payment information. If you still have an issue then ask your app buyer to go to their payment support help.

https://support.google.com/pay?ctx=paymentshc#topic=7625138

Click "Need more help" from the top right and select "Use Google Pay in App and Web Purchases" This will show Phone, Chat or Email Support.

OR for email support simply use https://support.google.com/pay/contact/general_email

Answer (score 0):

For International Transaction,
You need to update transaction setting of selected Credit/Debit Card with the help of internet banking

1. Enable Merchant Outlet
2. Enable Online Transaction